# A 'related content' list with DetailView in Django

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

Based on an "Article" model, I'm trying to display a "related content" list in the template by filtering its model field named "category". This "category" field has a ManyToMany relationship to another model named "Category".

It's looks like a very simple task but I can't figure out how to achieve my purpose. By now, a list could be displayed but seems nothing was filtered out.

Below is my DetailView class with a "get_context_data()" method which can product a template tag for displaying a list. Apparently the "F()" class is not the solution.

```
class ArticleDetail(generic.DetailView):
    model = Article
    template_name = 'article/detail.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ArticleDetail, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context_related = Article.objects.filter(F('category')).distinct()
        context['related'] = context_related

        return context
```

Besides, I also tried to filter with arguments like "category" and "category__exact=F('category')" but still failed.

And here are the models (simplified for question):

```
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content_text = models.TextField()
    category = models.ManyToManyField('Category', blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that's not what F() is for at all.

You don't explain exactly what you do want though. I presume you're looking for other articles in the same categories as the current article. That's easy enough:

```
Article.objects.filter(category__in=self.object.categories.all())
```